# Why is Dreamweaver telling me my files are locked when I can open them in other editors?

Tags: dreamweaver

I'm trying to edit html and dwt files that live on a shared server which I access through a VPN. When I try to edit them in Dreamweaver, I get the error

> ___.html is a locked file and can be viewed but not changed.

But I can edit the files in BBEdit (and presumably any other editor) without issue.

Editing the HTML files with BBEdit isn't an issue, but I need to edit dwt files and populate those changes to relevant pages, which I can't do with BBEdit.

I believe I have access to the files on a system level since I can edit them with BBEdit. So I'm not sure what else could be causing the issue.

I'm on a Mac. macOS Mojave. Having the issue with both Dreamweaver 2020 and 2021.

Comment: Dreamweaver is probably using its own way of signalling a lock (like through a specific separate hidden file), and other editors wouldn't know anything about it.

Comment: Look for `.lck` files and delete them.